# How to get a PFUser based on username

Tags: parse-platform, pfuser

I have a User class on Parse which has rows full of users.

I want to be able to simply query the table to get a PFUser based on username...

it seems like it should be done very easily, but I cannot figure it out. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do something like this.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:@"myUserName"]; // find the username
[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
if (!object) {
    NSLog(@"The getFirstObject request failed.");
} else {
// The find succeeded.
    NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved the user.");
    PFUser *myUser = (PFUser *) object;
}
}];
```